# Windows 8 - 4 updates keep failing and looping, how do I resolve them?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I have Windows 8.1 on an Asus Transformer laptop. Every some time my computer does a force-update. The last group of updates failed. Now, the cycle goes like this:

1. Every once in a while the computer force-restarts to apply the updates
2. It takes forever. Then it fails. It restarts again
3. Now it undoes the configurations. This takes forever. It restarts again.
4. It does some more undoing, then I can work.

And... That's it. If I open the update manager it just says the computer is pending updates (the same updates that keep failing!) and will force restart soon. I can't see a list to try and disable some of them to maybe find out which one is failing. I can't do anything, really.

How do I escape this madness?

Note: turning updates off is **not a solution**. I actually *want* the computer to install the updates. It's important. I just want it to work, somehow...

edit: I found the list under the history tab. Here they are and the related errors:

**Windows 8.1 Update for x64-based Systems (KB2919355)**
Error code: 80242014
Possible solution: windows support page [doesn't offer any good solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/windows-update-kb2919355-fails-to-install-error/aec97e6d-6b14-4bc6-a681-b418d8c13376?auth=1800F0922) to that despite a hoard of people complaining about the same issues as me

**Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB2922229)**
**Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB2939087)**
**Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB2962123) without KB2919355**
Error code: 80242014
Possible solution: [something to do with ESET](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-update/windows-updates-pending-error-code-80242014/d513d8cd-a6b7-4349-9702-f8b1b5cb239c). I don't have ESET so no solution

So the second group is possibly failing because of something to do with my antivirus, but I can't tell what (I have McAfee, it seems to work fine). I hardly installed anything on this computer. How can I resolve these? Thanks

Comment: Run Windows update from the control panel, then on select only one update to install, reboot if requested then do one more, repeat this process, hopefully all will get installed or least you will find the problem update.

Comment: @Moab Please read the question before commenting. I specifically mentioned that I can't do that and why

Comment: If you temporarily disable automatic updates it will clear any pending updates, then re enable updates using "download updates but ask before install" setting, then you can do a manual install of them one at a time. When done you can set it back to Automatic.

Comment: 80242014 = WU_E_UH_POSTREBOOTSTILLPENDING (The post-reboot operation for the update is still in progress). to see more details, coyp the folder C:\Windows\logs\CBS and the file C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log to your desktop, create a zip, upload the zip to OneDrive, create a share lik and post the lnk here

Comment: @magicandre1981 [here](http://1drv.ms/1jCzhrn)

Answer (score 0):

You always get the error `STATUS_TRANSACTION_NOT_ACTIVE`

> 2015-10-01 12:18:10, Error                 CSI    00000a17 (F)
>   **STATUS_TRANSACTION_NOT_ACTIV**E #22154418# from
>   Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey(flg
>   = (AllowKeyNotFound|AllowAccessDenied), key = {provider=NULL, handle=0, name= ("null")}, da = (KEY_READ|KEY_WOW64_64KEY), oa =
>   @0x46c17c790->OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES {s:48; rd:NULL;
>   on:[84]"\Registry\Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SideBySide\Configuration";
>   a:(OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE)}, disp = Unmapped disposition: 1813497216
>   (0x6c17c580))[gle=0xd0190003] 2015-10-01 12:18:10, Error
>   CSI    00000a18@2015/10/1:09:18:10.196 (F)
>   base\wcp\sil\merged\ntu\ntsystem.cpp(3813): Error
>   STATUS_TRANSACTION_NOT_ACTIVE originated in function
>   Windows::Rtl::SystemImplementation::DirectRegistryProvider::SysOpenKey
>   expression: (null) [gle=0x80004005]

Try to delete all files from `C:\Windows\System32\config\TxR` and run `fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\`

Does this help?

Comment: TxR seems empty (opening it I see no files, and yes, not hidden ones either). Trying to delete it prompts that some files are being used by System and therefore cannot be deleted. Should I run the command and restart anyway?

Comment: No. I tried it and it fails again :-(

Comment: try to repair your Windows 8: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26095-repair-install-windows-8-a.html